# How to choose a Candidate key in the given relation schema R?

Tags: database, rdbms, functional-dependencies

Consider the relation schema **R = (A, B, C, D, E, F)** and the set of functional dependencies:

```
A→B

A→C

BC→E

BC→D

E→F

BC→F
```

**Which is the candidate key of relation R?**

```
A) A

B) BC

C) ABC

D) ABCE
```

The standard answer given is C, which I should use ABC as candidate key in this relationship.

But since:

```
A -> B,C

B,C -> D,E,F
```

so I think A can identify all other attributes as

```
A -> B,C,D,E,F
```

Did I misunderstand the dependency relations?

Why can't I simply use A as candidate key to identify all the rest attributes?

Comment: Presumably you mean "functionally determines" not "can identify". What *chain of rules/axioms* can you use to show that A -> B, C & BC -> D imply ABC -> D? PS What does "dependency relations" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, a (candidate) key in this case is `A`, while `A B C` is a superkey.

Given the formal definition of candidate key as a “set of attributes that determines all the attributes of the relation and that lose this property by eliminating some attribute from it”, we can show that the closure of `A`, `A+`, determines all the attributes in this way:

```
A+ = A  (to compute the closure, we start with the attribute)
A+ = ABC (for transitivity with respect to A→B and A→C)
A+ = ABCDEF (for transitivity with respect to BC→E and BC→D and BC→F)
```

Moreover, it is easy to see that it is the unique set of attributes that has this property. In fact, `A` must be present in any (candidate) key, since it never appear on the right part of a functional dependency, so it is not determined by any other attribute or combination of attributes. But since it is already a (candidate) key, any set of attributes including it will be a proper superkey.